# fuelphpの中のpublicのphpファイルがブラウザに表示させれない。

Tags: apache, fuelphp, mamp

httpd -v
Server version: Apache/2.4.33 (Unix)
Server built:   Apr  3 2018 18:00:56

apache httpd.confの設定

```
ServerRoot "/Applications/MAMP/Library"
Listen 80
Listen 8080
ServerName localhost:80
DocumentRoot "/Users/■■■■/Desktop/fuel.7/public/hello"
Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
AllowOverride None
Directory "/Users/■■■■/Desktop/fuel.7"
AllowOverride All
AccessFileName .htaccess
```

fuelphpフォルダの中にpublicがあり、その中のhello.phpをブラウザで表示させたい

apache configtest
Syntax OK

URL
`http://localhost/hello`で打ち込むと

```
Not Found
he requested URL /hello was not found on this server.
```

となります。
何が原因と考えられるでしょうか。
apacheのhttpd.confの設定を変えるたびにapacheの再起動はしています。
他に必要な情報があれば提示します。
宜しくお願いします。

Comment: `hello.php`が具体的にどのフォルダに保存されているか、フルパスで記述することはできますか？あとは設定ファイル名が`https.conf`となっていますが、こちらは`httpd.conf`の間違いではないでしょうか？単なる質問文の記述ミスか、実際のファイル名がどうなっているかを念のため確認してみてください。

Comment: /Users/tanakaakio/Desktop/fuel.7/public/helloです。

Comment: https.confではなくhttpd.confです

Answer (score 1):

ドキュメントルートが`/Users/■■■■/Desktop/fuel.7/public/hello/`で、対象のファイルが`/Users/■■■■/Desktop/fuel.7/public/hello/hello.php`であるなら、アクセスする際のURLは
`localhost/hello.php`ではないでしょうか？